# How to show tab indicator on top of tab in android?

Tags: android, tabs

[image]
I have an app in which I have added `TabLayout`  with three tabs.   I want to show tab indicator from bottom to top but the problem is that when I show indicator from bottom to top tab icon also rotate.How do I resolve this issue?

```
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(view);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    mTabLayout.setRotationX(180);
```

Comment: can you plz share screenshot??

Comment: sure............

Comment: Please check screen shot

Comment: so yo want to attach tab layout vertically at left side of the screen  . . .right
???

Comment: When i change indicator to top icon of tab also rotate

Answer (score 0):

I have similar requirement in my previous application

Please try below code it works perfectly for me

```
//First rotate the tab layout
     tabOrderType.setRotationX(180);

//Find all childs for tablayout
            for (int i = 0; i <tabOrderType.getChildCount() ; i++) {
                    LinearLayout linearList = ((LinearLayout)tabOrderType.getChildAt(i));

                    for(int position = 0;position<linearList.getChildCount();position++) {
//One by one again rotate layout for text and icons
                        LinearLayout item=((LinearLayout) linearList.getChildAt(position));
                        item.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_button_border));
                        item.setRotationX(180);
                    }
                }
```

This is working nicely in my application and not creating any issue till now.Another way is you need to make custom tab to manage this.

Hope this helps you...if any issue please ask me...

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your TabLayout XML

```
app:tabIndicatorGravity="top"
```